# Unable to split a string with a back slash despite using escape character

Tags: python

I'm getting an error when I try to split a string like this:

```
string = "asdasd\asdasd"
lhs, rhs = string.split("\\")
print(rhs)
```

I receive the following error when I try to print the right hand side string.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Michael/PycharmProjects/untitled/expiriment2.py", line 2, in <module>
    lhs, rhs = string.split("\\")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: Your line, `string = "asdasd\asdasd"` doesn't have a backslash, it has an escape character (`\a`). Try changing it to `"asdasd\\asdasd"`

Comment: @BrandonBuck Thanks. The problem is that the backslash was a character that the original string contained. This is just a simpler example of what I am attempting to do.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked fine.

Comment: I had to convert the string to raw format. This worked for me.

Comment: Raw format and escaping the backslash accomplish the same goal. I tested exactly what I told you and it worked fine, raw works fine as well. I'm glad you were able to resolve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but you could try using raw strings like the following:

```
string = r"asdasd\asdasd"
lhs, rhs = string.split("\\")
print rhs
```

Answer (score 2):

Your string's backslash is being used to escape the following `a` character, so python treats `\a` as one character. You can check by printing your string to the console. It'll print `asdasdsdasd` instead of `asdasd\asdasd`. To ensure there is a backslash literal in your string, you must escape the escape character, i.e., put 2 backslashes.

`string = "asdasd\\asdasd"
lsh, rhs = string.split("\\")`

The reason you're getting that specific error is that split returns a list containing one element that is the original string (`["asdasd\asdasd"]`), so python is assigning `"asdasd\asdasd"` to `lhs`, and there is nothing to assign to `rhs`.

Answer (score 1):

```
lhs, rhs = string.split(r"\a")
```

The `r` indicates the following string is "raw" and that backslashes should not be escaped.

Comment: Interesting, but this solution hasn't worked for me. stus's solution worked fine.